# Select on a named pipe

Tags: windows, named-pipes

Is there a way to do a select() on a named pipe in win32? I want to have it block on the ReadFile call, but for only a few seconds, then if no data was received do some other work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot use select() on a named pipe in win32. For emulating select like functionality for named pipes, you can use the named pipe APIs using the overlapped I/O model and WaitForMultipleObjects().

[Click here for an example in MSDN for the same](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365603(VS.85).aspx)